# SQL query - using select twice inside delete

Tags: sql, oracle

Can i use select twice inside the delete, coz my requirement demands this, but am getting ORA-00936 "missing expression" error when tried in db.

```
DELETE FROM GLTB_REIM_DETAILS_TABLE_MAP WHERE
SELECT REPORT_NAME_C
FROM PRTB_REIM_REPORT_MAP, prtb_pay_remb_claims
WHERE (SELECT PAY_ELEMENT_CODE_C
  FROM PRTB_PAY_REMB_CLAIMS
  WHERE voucher_no_n='W288'
  AND emp_id_c      ='78881');
```

Help to solve this query!!!

Answer (score 1):

'Where' Condition seems to be incomplete. Please check once. You need to equate it with some paremeter. Check the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
DELETE FROM GLTB_REIM_DETAILS_TABLE_MAP A
 WHERE A.TABLEFIELD in (SELECT REPORT_NAME_C
    FROM PRTB_REIM_REPORT_MAP B, prtb_pay_remb_claims C
   WHERE B.TABLEFIELD in (SELECT PAY_ELEMENT_CODE_C
      FROM PRTB_PAY_REMB_CLAIMS
     WHERE voucher_no_n = 'W288'
       AND emp_id_c = '78881'));
```

Comment: why A , B & C is used?? am not sure how to use that??

Comment: alias ​,table to write the same field aspects and differences

Comment: sorry, not A, the TABLEFIELD refers to which table name's field ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you're are missing some join between the table PRTB_REIM_REPORT_MAP and prtb_pay_remb_claims. I shoud see the table declaration for be more helpful. But the delete statement should be something like that:

```
DELETE FROM GLTB_REIM_DETAILS_TABLE_MAP A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT REPORT_NAME_C
   FROM PRTB_REIM_REPORT_MAP, prtb_pay_remb_claims
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
      FROM PRTB_PAY_REMB_CLAIMS
      WHERE voucher_no_n = 'W288'
      AND emp_id_c = '78881'));
```

Comment: Yes it's not working. Like Pooh told you is something issing in the 'where' condition. Just tell us how to join each table. I can't help with all information.